# Typescript: Type X is missing the following properties from type Y length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more. [2740]

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have this Product interface:

```
export interface Product{
  code: string;
  description: string;
  type: string;
}
```

Service with method calling product endpoint:

```
  public getProducts(): Observable<Product> {
    return this.http.get<Product>(`api/products/v1/`);
  }
```

And component where I use this service to get the Products.

```
export class ShopComponent implements OnInit {
    public productsArray: Product[];
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(res => {
          this.productsArray = res;
        });
    }
}
```

With this state I'm getting error:

> [ts] Type 'Product' is missing the following properties from type
> 'Product[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more. [2740]

Removing typing on `productsArray` variable removes the error, but don't get why this is not working, since server response is an array of objects in the type of `Products`?

Comment: `getProducts()` is defined to return an `Observable` for a single `Product`, yet you assign the observed result to an `Product[]` array.

Comment: Small correction. Change the type to array

`return this.http.get<Product[]>(api/products/v1/);`

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You are returning `Observable<Product>` and expecting it to be `Product[]` inside `subscribe` callback.

The Type returned from `http.get()` and `getProducts()` should be `Observable<Product[]>`

```
public getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(`api/products/v1/`);
}
```

Comment: note: this requires "import { Observable } from 'rxjs';" in the service class

Answer (score 25):

You have forgotten to mark the getProducts return type as an array. In your getProducts it says that it will return a single product. So change it to this:

```
public getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(`api/products/v1/`);
  }
```

Comment: this works for me. in the Service we have to mention it as array Observable<Product[]> and get<Product[]>. thanks.

Answer (score 16):

For those newbies like me, don't assign variable to service response, meaning do

```
export class ShopComponent implements OnInit {
  public productsArray: Product[];

  ngOnInit() {
      this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(res => {
        this.productsArray = res;
      });
  }
}
```

Instead of

```
export class ShopComponent implements OnInit {
    public productsArray: Product[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.productsArray = this.productService.getProducts().subscribe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You must specify which type the response is:

```
this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(res => {
    this.productsArray = res;
});
```

Try this:

```
this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((res: Product[]) => {
    this.productsArray = res;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved as follows 
define an interface like mine

```
export class Notification {
    id: number;
    heading: string;
    link: string;
}
```

and in nofificationService write

```
allNotifications: Notification[]; 
  //NotificationDetail: Notification;  
  private notificationsUrl = 'assets/data/notification.json';  // URL to web api 
  private downloadsUrl = 'assets/data/download.json';  // URL to web api 

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient ) { }

  getNotifications(): Observable<Notification[]> {    
       //return this.allNotifications = this.NotificationDetail.slice(0);  
     return this.httpClient.get<Notification[]>

(this.notificationsUrl).pipe(map(res => this.allNotifications = res))
      }
```

and in component write

```
 constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
      /* get Notifications */
      this.notificationService.getNotifications().subscribe(data => this.notifications = data);
}
```

Comment: Why class not type ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message on GraphQL mutation input object then I found the problem, Actually in my case mutation expecting an object array as input but I'm trying to insert a single object as input. For example:

First try

```
const mutationName = await apolloClient.mutate<insert_mutation, insert_mutationVariables>({
      mutation: MUTATION,
      variables: {
        objects: {id: 1, name: "John Doe"},
      },
    });
```

Corrected mutation call as an array

```
const mutationName = await apolloClient.mutate<insert_mutation, insert_mutationVariables>({
      mutation: MUTATION,
      variables: {
        objects: [{id: 1, name: "John Doe"}],
      },
    });
```

Sometimes simple mistakes like this can cause the problems. Hope this'll help someone.

Answer (score 1):

For me the error was caused by wrong type hint of url string. I used:

```
export class TodoService {

  apiUrl: String = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos' // wrong uppercase String

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Todo[]>(this.apiUrl)
  }
}
```

where I should have used

```
export class TodoService {

  apiUrl: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos' // lowercase string!

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Todo[]>(this.apiUrl)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error could also be because you are not subscribing to the Observable.

Example, instead of:

```
this.products = this.productService.getProducts();
```

do this:

```
   this.productService.getProducts().subscribe({
    next: products=>this.products = products,
    error: err=>this.errorMessage = err
   });
```