# type 'never[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Customer[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I want to fetch `customers` list from my back-end via `get` `Http` call. But i am unable to declare `array` of `customers` in my `component`.

I have customer.interface.ts like this

```
export interface Customer {
  _id?: string,
  name: string,
  email: string,
  phone?: string,
  address?: string,
  age?: number
}
```

I have http.service.ts

```
get = (url: string): Observable<any> => {
 return this.http.get(this.createUrl(url), { headers: this.getHeaders() });
}
```

In my customer.service.ts

```
getCustomers(): Observable<Customer[]>{
 return this._http.get(ApiConstants.getCustomers);
}
```

In my customer.component.ts

```
customers$: Observable<Customer[]> = [];

ngOnInit(){
  this.customers$ = this.customerService.getCustomers();
}
```

Now it's giving me an error on this line `customers$: Observable<Customer[]> = []` like this inside editor at compile time.

```
Type 'never[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Customer[]>': isScalar, source, operator, lif and 5 more
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type of `customers$` is an `Observable`, so you can't assign an empty array to it. So you don't need to define it at all. This would be enough ->

```
customers$!: Observable<Customer[]>;
```

Add this `!` if your `"strictPropertyInitialization"` in `tsconfig.json` is set to `true`, if not you can omit it. This `!` is needed when you don't initialize the property straight away. You can set `"strictPropertyInitialization"` to `false` and then omit the `!`. You can take a look at [Property '...' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699067/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-construc)

Also, when you need to create an `Observable` out of something you can use `of` RxJS operator that converts the arguments to an observable sequence. https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of

One addition would be to add casting after `.get` to be more clear about the type.

```
getCustomers(): Observable<Customer[]> {
return this._http.get<Customer[]>(ApiConstants.getCustomers);
}
```

Answer of this question may help you [Typescript: Type X is missing the following properties from type Y length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more. [2740]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475893/typescript-type-x-is-missing-the-following-properties-from-type-y-length-pop)